# index method that responds to format.json keeps getting cached

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, caching, passenger

I have a Ruby on Rails website.

```
class DefinitionsController < ApplicationController
   caches_page :index
   def index
     responds_to do |format|
       format.json { render json: @something}
     end
   end
end
```

When I hit `myapp.host.com/definitions.json` I get my json data.
However when I call a function that uses `expire_page :action => :index` I won't get a fresh update of that data, it keeps getting serving the old json file from the `public` dir. Another url of the website that also gets expired, but is a normal page, does come up fresh then.

I use Rails 3, hosting using Nginx and Passenger. When I run it using `rails server` it does work ok, so it must be something with Nginx or Passenger.

Is there something special I need to do, like call `format => :json` on the `expire` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you haven't told `expire_page` the format of the cached content, so it assumes html. Finding no cached html content, it simply does nothing.

Try `expire_page :action => :index, :format => 'json'`.

Comment: This did indeed the trick. However, I still don't get why a general call to `expire_page` does not expire all formats.

Comment: @Peterdk I imagine the format is necessary in order for `expire_page` to know what files to delete. Your point is still a good one though. It's incongruent that `expire_page` is format-specific while `caches_page` is not format-specific. It's probably worth a comment on the rails core mailing list.